# Calculations using random numbers of a specific range in a 2D array in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, random

I have to populate a 2D array using random numbers between 3 and 19.

The array is **4 x 3**, the first two columns will represent two sides to a right triangle and the third column is the hypotenuse.

I'm pretty new to `C`, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. my output gives me the headers just fine but just one single vertical line of numbers instead of a **4 x 3** grid.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ROW 4
#define COL 3

void printChart(double array[ROW][COL]);

int main(void)
{
    double chart[ROW][COL];
    double *ptrchart = &chart[0][0];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0;j < COL;j++)
        {

            chart[i][j] = 3 + (rand() % 19);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        chart[i][2] = 0;
    }

    printChart(ptrchart);

    for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        chart[i][2] = (double)sqrt(pow(chart[i][0], 2) + pow(chart[i][1], 2));

    }

    puts(" ");

    printChart(ptrchart);

    return 0;

}

void printChart(double array[ROW][COL])
{
    printf("%s", "Side A\tSide B\tHypotenuse(Side C)\n");
    for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0;j < COL;j++)
        {
            printf("%.3f\t",  array[i][j]);

            if (j = 2)
            {
                puts(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I need to clarify anything please let me know.

Comment: `printChart(ptrchart);` should be `printChart(chart);` to match the prototype and `if (j = 2)` should be `if (j == 2)`: https://ideone.com/6lpHOr

Comment: I've been staring at my code for about two hours now and can't believe I missed the ( j == 2) part. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, C has a function for computing `sqrt(pow(chart[i][0], 2) + pow(chart[i][1], 2))`: `hypot(chart[i][0], chart[i][1])`. It will not overflow if the result does not overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just put (j==2) instead of (j=2) in your function since it changes j to always be 2 the way you wrote it

I ran the below code and it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ROW 4
#define COL 3

void printChart(double array[ROW][COL])
{
printf("%s", "Side A\tSide B\tHypotenuse(Side C)\n");
for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0;j < COL;j++)
    {
        printf("%.3f\t",  array[i][j]);

        if (j == 2)
        {
            puts(" ");
        }
    }
}
}

int main(void)
{
double chart[ROW][COL];
double *ptrchart = &chart[0][0];

srand(time(NULL));
for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0;j < COL;j++)
    {

        chart[i][j] = 3 + (rand() % 19);
    }
}
for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
{
    chart[i][2] = 0;
}
for (size_t i = 0;i < ROW;i++)
{
    chart[i][2] = (double)sqrt(pow(chart[i][0], 2) + pow(chart[i][1], 2));
}
puts(" ");
printChart(ptrchart);
return 0;

}
```